# Ask Basic Configurator in Apache Commong Log

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I use log4j as logger for my web application. in log4j, I can set the level log in log4j properties or log4j.xml.
in log4j, we instance logger as follows:

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
```

I init log4j basic configurator in a `servlet file using init method`.
But, I usually test application `using JUnit`, So I init the `basic configurator in setup method`. after that, I test the application, and I can see the log.

Because I deployed, the web in `websphere`. I change all of logging instance become:

```
private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Foo.class);
```

I don't know how to load basic configurator using ACL. so I can't control debug level to my JUnit test.

do you have any suggestion, without changing

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
```

become

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What logging system you use as backend for Apache Commons Logging in Websphere in your unit tests? ACL is just a wrapper for other logging backends (such as log4j), and you configure logging level using backends configuration facilities.

So I think you should just use log4j in your unit tests and use its basic configuration in `setup` methods.

Comment: I just use ACL in my component. private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Foo.class);, If I use log4j for basic configuration in my setup method. I must change private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Foo.class); for every class that I have developed become static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);. that's I want to avoid for

Comment: ACL delegates logging to some other logging framework, if you are not using anything specifically, then it probably goes to java.util.logging. Configure that in your tests.